# If statements not working when using JavaFX?

Tags: java

I'm not quite sure why my if statement is not working. Can someone explain to me the correct way of doing this while using JavaFX? I just want the if statement to print a line when my counter reaches 10.

Here's the code:

```
package test.application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestApplication extends Application {

    private Button button;
    private Stage stage;
    private StackPane layout;
    private Scene scene;
    private int count;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Initialize main GUI items
        stage = new Stage();
        button = new Button("Test");
        layout = new StackPane();
        scene = new Scene(layout, 400, 400);
        count = 0;

        // Add button
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        });

        if (count == 10) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }

        primaryStage.setTitle("Swag");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your count-variable will never reach 10 when the application is initialized.

You'll have to put your if-statement into the setOnAction-Event.

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
    if(count == 10){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
});
```